OPC-UA Python asyncua, Authentification using certificats
I'm testing the asyncua lib in python (opcua-asyncua).
I want to test the authentification with certificates : client - server.
I used a local CA to sign my CSR from both client and server :
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem ../server/asyncua_opcua_server_cert.pem

../server/asyncua_opcua_server_cert.pem: OK
openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem ../client/asyncua_opcua_client_cert.pem

../client/asyncua_opcua_client_cert.pem: OK
I also used the example from GitHub :
[server-with.encryption.py][1]
[client-with-encryption.py][2]
I modified a little bit both of the files :
server :
import asyncio
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import socket

import logging

sys.path.insert(0, "..")
from asyncua import Server
from asyncua import ua
from asyncua.server.user_managers import CertificateUserManager
from asyncua.crypto.cert_gen import setup_self_signed_certificate
from asyncua.crypto.validator import CertificateValidator, CertificateValidatorOptions
from cryptography.x509.oid import ExtendedKeyUsageOID
from asyncua.crypto.truststore import TrustStore
from asyncua.common.methods import uamethod


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


USE_TRUST_STORE = True 

@uamethod
def func(parent, value):
    return value * 2

async def main():
    _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    cert_base = Path(__file__).parent
    certificate_local_path = Path(cert_base/ "certificate/server/asyncua_opcua_server_cert_subjectAltName.pem")
    private_key_local_path =Path(cert_base/ "certificate/server/asyncua_opcua_server_key.pem")
    host_name = socket.gethostname()
    server_app_uri = "asyncua:python:DNAMIC:server"

    server = Server()
    await server.init()

    await server.set_application_uri(server_app_uri)
    server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://0.0.0.0:4840/freeopcua/server/")
    server.set_security_policy([ua.SecurityPolicyType.Basic256Sha256_Sign, ua.SecurityPolicyType.Basic256Sha256_SignAndEncrypt])
    policyIDs = ["Basic256Sha256"]         
    server.set_security_IDs(policyIDs)
    _logger.info("Security IDs du serveur : %s",policyIDs)
    # load server certificate and private key. This enables endpoints
    # with signing and encryption.
    await server.load_certificate(certificate_local_path)
    await server.load_private_key(private_key_local_path)

    if USE_TRUST_STORE:
        trust_store = TrustStore([Path(cert_base/ "certificate/ca")], [])
        await trust_store.load()
        validator = CertificateValidator(
            options=CertificateValidatorOptions.TRUSTED_VALIDATION | CertificateValidatorOptions.PEER_CLIENT,
            trust_store=trust_store,
        )
    else:
        validator = CertificateValidator(
            options=CertificateValidatorOptions.EXT_VALIDATION | CertificateValidatorOptions.PEER_CLIENT
        )
    server.set_certificate_validator(validator)

    idx = 0

    # populating our address space
    myobj = await server.nodes.objects.add_object(idx, "MyObject")
    myvar = await myobj.add_variable(idx, "MyVariable", 0.0)
    await myvar.set_writable()  # Set MyVariable to be writable by clients
    await server.nodes.objects.add_method(
        ua.NodeId("ServerMethod", idx),
        ua.QualifiedName("ServerMethod", idx),
        func,
        [ua.VariantType.Int64],
        [ua.VariantType.Int64],
    )

    # starting!
    async with server:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            current_val = await myvar.get_value()
            count = current_val + 0.1
            await myvar.write_value(count)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    asyncio.run(main())  


client:
import asyncio
import logging
import sys
import socket
from pathlib import Path
from cryptography.x509.oid import ExtendedKeyUsageOID

sys.path.insert(0, "..")
from asyncua import Client
from asyncua.crypto.security_policies import SecurityPolicyBasic256Sha256
from asyncua.crypto.cert_gen import setup_self_signed_certificate
from asyncua.crypto.validator import CertificateValidator, CertificateValidatorOptions
from asyncua.crypto.truststore import TrustStore
from asyncua import ua


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

USE_TRUST_STORE = True

cert_idx = 4

async def task(loop):
    host_name = socket.gethostname()
    client_app_uri = f"urn:{host_name}:foobar:myselfsignedclient"
    url = "opc.tcp://localhost:4840/freeopcua/server/"

    cert_base = Path(__file__).parent
    cert = Path(cert_base / "certificate/client/asyncua_opcua_client_cert_subjectAltName.pem")
    private_key = Path(cert_base / "certificate/client/asyncua_opcua_client_key.pem")
    ca_cert = Path(cert_base /"certificate/ca/ca.pem")

    client = Client(url=url)
    #client.application_uri = client_app_uri
    client.application_uri = "asyncua:python:DNAMIC:client"
    await client.set_security(
        policy=SecurityPolicyBasic256Sha256,
        certificate=str(cert),
        private_key=str(private_key),
        server_certificate=str(ca_cert),
    )

    if USE_TRUST_STORE:
        trust_store = TrustStore([Path(cert_base / "certificate/ca")], [])
        await trust_store.load()
        validator = CertificateValidator(
            CertificateValidatorOptions.TRUSTED_VALIDATION | CertificateValidatorOptions.PEER_SERVER, trust_store
        )
    else:
        validator = CertificateValidator(
            CertificateValidatorOptions.EXT_VALIDATION | CertificateValidatorOptions.PEER_SERVER
        )
    client.certificate_validator = validator
    try:
        async with client:
            objects = client.nodes.objects
            child = await objects.get_child(["0:MyObject", "0:MyVariable"])
            _logger.info(f"child : {child}")
        #test lecture variable OPC-UA
            print(await child.get_value())
        #test écriture variable OPC-UA
            #await child.write_value(42)
        #test appel méthode OPC-UA
            res = await client.nodes.objects.call_method("ServerMethod", 7)
            print(f"Calling ServerMethod returned {res}")
    except ua.UaError as exp:
        _logger.error(exp)


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_debug(True)
    loop.run_until_complete(task(loop))
    loop.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

when I try to connect my client to the server I get from the client's console :
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError  

server's console:
INFO:asyncua.server.binary_server_asyncio:New connection from ('127.0.0.1', 46434)
INFO:asyncua.uaprotocol:updating server limits to: TransportLimits(max_recv_buffer=65535, max_send_buffer=65535, max_chunk_count=1601, max_message_size=104857600)
ERROR:asyncua.server.binary_server_asyncio:Exception raised while processing message from client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arnaud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncua/server/binary_server_asyncio.py", line 99, in _process_received_message_loop
    await self._process_one_msg(header, buf)
  File "/home/arnaud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncua/server/binary_server_asyncio.py", line 105, in _process_one_msg
    ret = await self.processor.process(header, buf)
  File "/home/arnaud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncua/server/uaprocessor.py", line 104, in process
    msg = self._connection.receive_from_header_and_body(header, body)
  File "/home/arnaud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncua/common/connection.py", line 415, in receive_from_header_and_body
    chunk = MessageChunk.from_header_and_body(self.security_policy, header, body, use_prev_key=False)
  File "/home/arnaud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncua/common/connection.py", line 125, in from_header_and_body
    decrypted = crypto.decrypt(data.read(len(data)))
  File "/home/arnaud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncua/crypto/security_policies.py", line 198, in decrypt
    return self.Decryptor.decrypt(data)
  File "/home/arnaud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncua/crypto/security_policies.py", line 309, in decrypt
    decrypted += self.decryptor(self.client_pk,
  File "/home/arnaud/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncua/crypto/uacrypto.py", line 200, in decrypt_rsa_oaep
    text = private_key.decrypt(
ValueError: Decryption failed
INFO:asyncua.server.binary_server_asyncio:Lost connection from ('127.0.0.1', 46434), None
INFO:asyncua.server.uaprocessor:Cleanup client connection: ('127.0.0.1', 46434)

I think we don't have any documentation for asyncua so it's hard for me to find what I'm doing wrong  any Idea ?
[1]: https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/server-with-encryption.py
[2]: https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/blob/master/examples/client-with-encryption.py

Okey I found that you have to load your certificate and private key in the client side code:
await client.load_client_certificate(cert)
await client.load_private_key(private_key)

now I'm able to connect to my server using my cert and the TrustStore
However, I'm not sure I'm using these mechanisms correctly:
I tried to connect with a self-signed client certificate, the server refuses me the connection which seems to be a good point.
But if I disable the truststore on the client and server side and use the client certificate signed by my CA, I'm still able to authenticate myself and connect, is this normal?
From what I understand, the certificateUserManager is only useful for managing self-signed certificates, which is not my use case.
